# Stripe Webhooks - Design Pattern

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, stripe-payments, webhooks

I have a design for handling Stripe webhooks, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to handle them.

- Subscription product
- Webhook events can arrive in any order, and there can be duplicate events
- I'm using Flask, and doing the event handling in the endpoint (/webhooks)

1. When the endpoint receives an event, it pulls all events associated with the customer id.

```
event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
        )

customer_id = event['data']['object']['customer']

#Filtering down to only the event types I need. I could do this from the Stripe dashboard as well
all_events_dict = json.loads(str(stripe.Event.list(related_object=customer_id, types=['...'])))
```

2. I have some logic for processing the events, and adding them to the database so I don't re-process the event

```
events_to_process = []

    for event in all_events_dict['data']:
        event_id = event['id']

        if event_id not in events_to_process and not StripeEvent.query.filter_by(stripe_event_id=event_id).first():
            event_type = event['type']
            event_created = event['created']

            events_to_process.append(event_id)

            stripe_event = StripeEvent(stripe_event_id=event_id,
                                        event_type=event_type,
                                        event_created=event_created,
                                        event_json=str(event))
            db.session.add(stripe_event)
        
         db.session.commit()
```

**Issue #1:** Even though I'm checking to see if the event already exists  (using StripeEvent.query), often I still get an IntegrityError (duplicate key value violates unique constraint) for stripe_event_id, the primary key. I think this is because there are many requests from Stripe for /webhooks firing at once, so there are multiple events that make it past the conditional at roughly the same time.

**Issue #2:** I'm hitting the database a lot, I think Quadtratic N^2? For each event, I query the database once for every event. So if there are 10 events, I query the database 100 times. Not sure if this can be avoided.

3. Next I'm creating variables for the event objects. I do this, rather than just iterating over all_events_dict, because I want to be able to control the order in which events are processed.

```
customer_created = next((item for item in all_events_dict['data'] if item['type'] == 'customer.created' and item['id'] in events_to_process), None)

subscription_created = next((item for item in all_events_dict['data'] if item['type'] == 'customer.subscription.created'
                                and item['id'] in events_to_process and not Subscription.query.filter_by(id=item['data']['object']['id']).first()), None)

...
```

4. I go through the variables I've created sequentially

```
    if subscription_created:
        subscription_id = subscription_created['data']['object']['id']

        current_subscription = Subscription.query.filter_by(id=subscription_id).first()
        if not current_subscription:
            subscription = Subscription()
            
            # The processing logic is abstracted as function in the data model
            subscription.add_subscription(subscription_created)

            db.session.add(subscription)
            db.session.commit()

        else:
            current_subscription.update_subscription(subscription_created)

            db.session.commit()

    if subscription_updated:
        subscription_id = subscription_updated['data']['object']['id']
        event_created = subscription_updated['created']

        current_subscription = Subscription.query.filter_by(id=subscription_id).first()

        if current_subscription and event_created > current_subscription.last_updated:
            current_subscription.update_subscription(subscription_updated)

            db.session.commit()
```

**Issue #4:** Duplicate events can cause the same IntegrityError I described above in issue #1.

**Issue #5:** If I process the events as described in steps 1-3 (pulling every event for each event), then this works OK. However, `subscription.updated` can come at any time, including before the `customer.subscription.created` event. This means I'd have to add logic to add the subscription to the database using the `subscription.updated` event. I think this would work for subscriptions, but if I extend it out to other event types I think there are cases where the `....updated` event doesn't contain all the data I need.

These are some of the issues I see, but overall I'm looking for any feedback on the design to process Stripe events. I can get the above working, but it seems ham-handed. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: is this all 1 function?

Comment: It's all in the route: `@payments_bp.route('/webhooks', methods=['POST'])` \n `def webhooks():`

Comment: I didn't down vote it, but most of your question might be better suited for the code review site. You shouldn't be fetching the events at the same time that stripe is posting events to your endpoint. Just let stripe send each event that you're subscribed to and handle them as they are received.

Answer (score 1):

This needs more focus - the "ideal" architecture or pattern here depends on the details of your business and exactly what information you use/need.

Broadly, though: you should defer the subsequent processing. Instead of querying anything when you get an event you should check the signature, queue this event somewhere else and [respond with a successful delivery response as quick as possible](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/build#return-a-2xx-status-code-quickly).

By acknowledging receipt and queuing the event for processing asynchronously, you can have much more control over de-duplication and sibling events.